# FreeBSD data structure and communication

Tags: c, data-structures, kernel, freebsd

I am doing a freeBSD project, the requirement is to write four system call:

```
1. set_containerid(int idnum, pid_t pid)
      //set given pid's container ID to idnum
      //child process should inherit parent's containerID
2.create_container(int perms, char *name)
      //perm = 0 means allowing other processes to read/write this container
3.destroy_container(char *name)
4. write_container(char *name, char *message, int len)
5.read_container(char *name, char *message, int len)
```

So, I know I need a linked list to hold my own data structure

```
Container{
  char* name;
  char* buf;
}
```

I am wondering where do i put this linked list so that every process can access it?

BTW, changing system files is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Are these really system calls?  I'd need more information to give you a comprehensive answer, but...

I would look at implementing them as a user library in /usr/local/lib and /usr/local/include rather than trying to put them into the kernel.

Debugging kernel modules is tricky to say the least.  Adding new system calls means forking the OS because the FreeBSD kernel team may decide to add additional calls themselves, and they'll over-write yours.

Assuming they do need to be syscalls, then the easiest way to write this would be to write a container device driver - that way, it can be done as a kernel-loadable module and doesn't interfere with the syscall numbering/naming scheme. The device driver would present a character dev entry (such as /dev/container) and you could then produce a library to interface the writer_container function into a write(2) on the device. Likewise, the create, set and destroy could be done with an ioctl(2) on the device.

Either way, you'll end up with a .h and a .a in /usr/local, to provide the interface required. Why did you capitalize Container, btw?